# Why isn't my Azure Website accepting OAuth tokens?

Tags: azure, oauth, claims-based-identity, azure-active-directory

I want my application to accept OAuth tokens when hosted using Azure Websites. I have the following:

web.config of web app

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://example.com/development" />
  <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://example.com/development" />
  <add key="ida:Tenant" value="example.com" />
</appSettings>
```

Startup.cs of web app

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Configuration;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApplication.Web.Startup))]

namespace MyApplication.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {    
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceUri"]
                    },
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

void Main()
{
    var clientId = @"GUIDGUIDGUID";
    var key = @"KEYKEYKEYKEYKEY";
    var aadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
    var tenant = "example.com";
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant), true);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, key);
    authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
    var token = authContext.AcquireToken(@"https://example.com/development", credential);
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
        var response = client.GetAsync(@"https://app.example.com/").Result;
        var responseText = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        Console.Write(new StreamReader(responseText).ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: I assume that you can get a correct token, is it right? What error code do you get from the service?

In general I see no reason of this code to fail.  Can you access your service allowing anonimous access to any method for example?

BTW you are using older token endpoint though it can't be a reason (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0} is new).

Comment: @Igor It just started working this morning... I guess I had to let it sit for a bit. Thank you for the heads up about the old endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I was using the `Uri` class to validate the App ID URI. Problem is, it adds a trailing slash onto to the end, which causes problems. As soon as I started using the `string` class to store the App ID URI, it was fine.

So make sure you are using exactly the values seen in Azure AD!